# Subtract-a-Square game in Java

Tags: java, boolean

The assignment is writing the two-player game Subtract-a-Square using Java. The players make turns subtracting a square number and a player emerges victirous if he makes the final move. We are supposed to implement the function **boolean isSquare(int a)** to check if the number entered is a square and the user input is legal. I've done the boolean to check if it's a square, but I fail to find a way to make the two players make alternating turns. Thank you!

```
public class Squares {
  public static void main(String[] args) { 

    int sum = (int)(Math.random()*11)+10;

    while(!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
      int i = 1;
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        int P1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        sum = sum - P1;
      }
      else {
        int P2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        sum = sum - P2;
      }
      i++;
    }
  }

  public static boolean isSquare(int a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
     //   sum = sum - player input 
    }

    if (a < 0 || a > sum)
      System.out.println("Wrong input: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < a / 2 + 2; i++) {
        if (i * i == a)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: right now you are using args as your input, you'll want to use System.in as your input. Look up "getting user input JAVA" and there will be plenty of examples on how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

Let us take you have two players Alice and Bob. Player making turns means first you should take an input from the screen and consider it as input by Alice. Next input will be considered as Bob's input. Next input will be considered as Alice's input and so on..

so,

```
1st input = ALice
2nd input = Bob
3rd input = Alice
4th input = Bob
```

Use some count variable to count the number of inputs. You have to take input using Scanner.
If you observe the pattern, if the input is odd input, then it is Alice's input. Or else it is Bob's input. So, if the final move is in Odd input, then Alice is winner. Or else Bob is winner.

Comment: Thank you. I have now revised the code in the description after your suggestion. I'm hopefully on  the right track.